GitLab Issue URL using ids
Is there a way to create a GitLab Issue URL without using the project path? I want to use either

Issue global ID
Project ID and issue internal ID

Example:

Issue URL with project path: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/465967
Project ID: 278964
Issue internal ID: 465967
Issue global ID: 147492775

I get the ids from an event API call and want to create a URL to the issue. The project path is not part of the event response.
As I want to avoid unnecessary API calls I would prefer to create a working URL using only IDs.
Workaround is to make an API call to get the project URL.
Working:

URL to project using the id: https://gitlab.com/projects/278964

Not working (404 errors):

https://gitlab.com/projects/278964/issues/465967
https://gitlab.com/projects/278964/-/issues/465967
https://gitlab.com/issues/147492775

